# How to join multiple mongoDB Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nodes

Here I have three collections.

**Category**

```
category: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "cat 1",
      status:true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "cat 2",
      status:true
    }
  ]
```

**Item**

```
item: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "item 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "item 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "item 3"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "item 4"
    }
  ]
```

**Package**

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "package 1",
      categoryId: 1,
      items: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          itemId: 1
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          itemId: 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "package 2",
      categoryId: 2,
      items: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          itemId: 3
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          itemId: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to get all `packages` along with `items object` on category wise, and each category status should be true. I want to list all packages based on the category.

Column CategoryId of collection package is a foreign key.

Column ItemId of collection package is a foreign key.

**Expected output**

```
[
    {
        name:'cat 1',
        status:true,
        package:[
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "package 1",
                categoryId: 1,
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "item 1"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "item 2"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name:'cat 2',
        status:true,
        package:[
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "package 2",
                categoryId: 2,
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: "item 3"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        name: "item 4"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

for reference : https://mongoplayground.net/p/83z0Hcgh04i

Comment: I came up with this, https://mongoplayground.net/p/hU7iIU0ywwB If it is what you need i will upload a detailed answer later

Comment: Yes. Please upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the expected result we must perform some steps on the data, we will explain each of this steps. You can see the full query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/llzx0u7UEXw).

The operation tha we must use  on the `category` DB is an `aggregation`

```
db.category.aggregate([])
```

Inside this function we will put each step inside the array.
The first one is a `lookup`, we will get the packages that matches each category an stored them in the `packages`field

```
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "package",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "categoryId",
      "as": "packages"
    }
}
```

Since we need the items info to populate each one and the items are inside each package, we must separe them. We will `unwind` the packages and the items.

```
  {
    "$unwind": "$packages"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$packages.items"
  }
```

Now we can match each item with his information, with another `lookup` and stored them inside each package.

```
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "items",
      "localField": "packages.items.itemId",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "packages.items"
    }
  }
```

Because doing a `lookup` give us an array, we will use another `unwind` to make sure there is only one item per document before groping.

```
  {
    "$unwind": "$packages.items"
  }
```

At this moment we have all the date that we wanted, but we have to group it again, becouse we separated it before with the `unwind`. To perfomr this we will use `group` on the `packages.id` . We will format the fields that we want, push all items together and save some aux data in the `root` field for later.

```
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$packages.id",
      name: {
        "$first": "$packages.name"
      },
      "brandId": {
        "$first": "$packages.brandId"
      },
      "categoryId": {
        "$first": "$packages.categoryId"
      },
      root: {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "items": {
        "$push": "$packages.items"
      }
    }
  }
```

At this step we have all the packages together, we must `group`a gain by `category`. To do this we will use the aux data store in `root`.

```
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$root.id",
      name: {
        "$first": "$root.name"
      },
      "packages": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
```

Finally we will erase the aux `root` field.

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "packages.root": 0
    }
  }
```

Comment: But  items  object should be json object not json array.

Comment: Now its
items": [
          [
            {
              "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
              "id": 3,
              "name": "item 3"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
              "id": 4,
              "name": "item 4"
            }
          ]
        ],

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer adding another `$unwind` step to avoid that.